# How to display a csv file data within a react data grid component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, datagridview

How do i load data from a csv file on to a react data grid component.

I want to load data to this table
**https://react.rocks/example/react-spreadsheet**

Answer (score 0):

you need parse data from your CSV file, then make structure of your array like component accept. and pass to it